TV show or movie: doctor takes boy into wormholes, black man in robot suit
I saw a movie a long time ago, when I was a child. I remember scenes, like the movie starts with a boy who finds in his dog's house something like a skeleton bone, and after that a doctor in a caravan arrives and takes him into wormholes, I think. And I remember that a black man in a robot suit folows them trying to stop them from getting all the missing pieces from that skeleton. 

When did you see this film (i.e. when were you a child)? How old was it? Where/when was it set? Was it an American film or what? Every little detail you can remember might help somebody to identify it for you!

Marked as a duplicate since it sounds like you're looking for Josh Kirby. If it's not the right answer, please let me know.

YES, is Josh KIRBY, THANK YOU A LOT!!!

Confirmed as a dupe of Movie about a guy who goes to a toy dimension.
